# How can I reach specific Facebook users who are not connected to my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it **anyhow** possible to reach a Facebook user through a Facebook app who is **not** a user of the app?

The only way I found so far is to send an email to {username}@facebook.com, but this message will go to the "other" folder.
Further, I guess an app cannot make use of the "paid messaging" feature? (Users who are not connected to each other can pay $1.00 to send a message to someones inbox).

Is there any other way? (Notifications? Requests?)

**Edit:**

Here is an example:
Imagine an app where you can send gifts or greeting cards.
User A is connected to the app and sends a gift to User B (who isn't a user of the App). How can User B learn about his gift? Hard mode: User B isn't connected with User A.

Comment: Are you asking for a good promotional strategy for your APP on SO?

Comment: No. Please read the question again, I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can User B learn about his gift?

- by User A making a post on their wall (if User A is allowed to do so) -> Feed dialog
- by User A sending them a private message -> Send dialog
- by User A asking them to join the app -> invite via Request dialog

Comment: Thank you, but what is User A isn't connected to User B?
Actually the question is how can the App reach User B, not how User A can reach User B.

Comment: Then the only way would be the username@facebook.com email address – but it is explicitly stated that those are meant for user-to-user communication only, and not for apps to communicate with their users (and much less so, if they are not even users of your app). The “business model” of your app is something that does not really fit with Facebook’s tools, API and possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. You mentioned that Facebook has explicit policies regarding username@facebook.com addresses, do you have a source?