# Is Facebook's "paid messaging" feature available via some API?

Tags: facebook

When test driving the [SendDialog API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), I noticed that the option to pay some fee (usually $1) to deliver the message in recipient's inbox is not available in cases where the "Send Message" in FB's own site would be.

Is this feature available through some other API so that a third party app/web site could offer a similar option of attempting to deliver to a recipient's inbox in exchange of a fee?

This question was also asked as an aside in [How can I reach specific Facebook users who are not connected to my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20209546/2004714) and received no explicit "yes" or "no" on this particular aspect. It appears that the answer could be "no" but still wanted to ask for an explicit answer to this in order to confirm.

Thanks in advance.